# In XPATH I use '''...and''' to add an additional criterion, in cheerio is there this option?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, cheerio

I use the cheeriogs library to work in Google App Script:
id library: `1ReeQ6WO8kKNxoaA_O0XEQ589cIrRvEBA9qcWpNqdOP17i47u6N9M5Xh0`

Using `=IMPORTXML('url','xpath')` I make the call with this XPATH:

`//div[contains(@class,'match-card') and ../../td[@class='score-time ']/a[contains(@href, 'matches')]]`

The idea is to collect the `div` that contain the `@class` with the word `match-card`
BUT
he needs to have `td` linked to `@class='score-time'` and `a` contains the `@href` with the word `matches`

I tried to find a way to do this with CHEERIOGS but it always returns blank, my attempts were:

```
    $('tr:contains(td.score-time > a[href^="/matches/"]) > div[class^="match-card"]')
                  .each((index, element) => {ss.getRange(index + 2, 2).setValue($(element).text().trim());});
```

```
    $('tr td.score-time:contains(a[href^="/matches/"]) > div[class^="match-card"]')
                  .each((index, element) => {ss.getRange(index + 2, 2).setValue($(element).text().trim());});
```

```
    $('tr td.score-time > a[href^="/matches/"] > div[class^="match-card"]')
                  .each((index, element) => {ss.getRange(index + 2, 2).setValue($(element).text().trim());});
```

How I could go about achieving my expected result?

*Additional information via requests in the comments:*

Example link:

https://int.soccerway.com/national/finland/suomen-cup/20212022/2nd-round/r67751/

The expected result is to collect the values in red when there are links embedded in blue:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the URL for testing it?

Comment: Sure mate @Tanaike , i'm so sorry for not add in question! https://int.soccerway.com/national/finland/suomen-cup/20212022/2nd-round/r67751/

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide the sample values you expect? Because `match-card` is not included in `td.score-time` in the HTML of your provided URL. So I cannot understand your expected values. I apologize for this. So, when your provided xpath of `//tr//div[contains(@class, 'match-card') and ../../tr//td[@class='score-time']/a[contains(@href, 'matches')]]` is used, no values are returned. Is this the related to your current issue?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike I added the expected result in the question

Comment: @Tanaike there was an error in the XPATH used in IMPORTXML, I already adjusted in the question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About the values of the red square, I understood them. But I cannot understand the blue square. Can I ask you about the detail of the values you expect? For example, do you want to retrieve the URL of the image?

Comment: When I tested your provided xpath, 9 values are retrieved. But in the HTML of your provided URL and your provided image, more values are existing. So, I'm confusing your question. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the values you want to retrieve?

Comment: @Tanaike For example, when you click inspect right over the ```-``` value in the first game, there is a ```url``` attached: ```href="/matches/2022/03/27/finland/suomen-cup/oujk/roi-united/3751971/"``` BUT If you inspect a ```-``` in blue there in the last few games, there is no ```url```, so when there is no ```url``` → ```<a href="">```, I don't want it to return the value in red.

Comment: And perfect, in this case it has to return only ```9``` values, because only the first ```9``` games that have a ```href``` with ```url```.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your latest reply, I could understand. But I cannot understand your expected values. In your blue square in the image, you want to retrieve the URL of the URL of `a` tag just under `score-time` of `div` tag. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I want to get the time the game starts ```class="match-card```, like for example the first game starts at ```07:00``` (Maybe the time for you is different because of the time zone). But this hours only the games that have url value in ```@class='score-time' → a → href```

Comment: @Tanaike The ```match-card``` can be two names, ```@class='match-card match-hour'``` or ```@class='match-card match-current-minute'```, so I used ```contains(@class,'match-card')``` to combine the two options into one turn.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```
const values = [];
$("tr.expanded").each((_, element) => {
  var v1 = $(element).find('span').attr('data-value');
  var v2 = $(element).find('td.score-time > a').attr('href');
  if (v2) {
    values.push([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Number(v1) * 1000), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm"), v2]);
  }
});
console.log(values);

// If you want to put the values to the Spreadsheet, please use this. `ss` from your showing script.
ss.getRange(2, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

#### Result:

When this script is run for the URL of `https://int.soccerway.com/national/finland/suomen-cup/20212022/2nd-round/r67751/`, the following result is obtained.

```json
[
  ["19:00","/matches/2022/03/27/finland/suomen-cup/oujk/roi-united/3751971/"],
  ["21:30","/matches/2022/03/27/finland/suomen-cup/puleward-city/tornion-pallo-47/3751969/"],
  ["07:00","/matches/2022/03/30/finland/suomen-cup/rastaala/valtti/3751935/"],
  ["07:00","/matches/2022/03/30/finland/suomen-cup/hapk/japs-ii/3751944/"],
  ["07:00","/matches/2022/03/30/finland/suomen-cup/japs-o35/finland-kumu-junior-team/3751949/"],
  ["07:00","/matches/2022/03/30/finland/suomen-cup/harjun-potku/sc-riverball/3751963/"],
  ["07:00","/matches/2022/03/30/finland/suomen-cup/fcs/jyvaskylan-seudun-palloseura/3751965/"],
  ["07:00","/matches/2022/03/30/finland/suomen-cup/barca/kuopion-elo/3751967/"],
  ["07:00","/matches/2022/03/30/finland/suomen-cup/pallo-kerho-37/pupa-o35/3751968/"]
]
```

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

That would be the :has pseudo:

```
td.day:has(~ td.score-time a[href*="matches"])
```

This might not be available in the version you're using though